# How does aminoguanidine interfere with the formation of advanced glycation endproducts?

Tags: biochemistry

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimagedine) says that aminoguanidine interferes with the formation of advanced glycation endproducts (AGEs) through interacting with 3-deoxyglucosone.

But how does it interact with 3-deoxyglucosone that prevents AGE formation?

Comment: What is AGE? Please define your acronyms for the benefit of those who are not familiar with the jargon.

Comment: okay i've added it

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the N-amino group of aminoguanidine to react with 3-deoxyglucosone at either of the adjacent, reactive carbonyl groups to form a stable guanidinylimine derivative (analogous to a hydrazone). This derivative, unlike 3-deoxyglucosone itself, would not be able to react with free amino groups on proteins and continue on the pathway to AGEs, but rather would be excreted as is.